# How can you mirror a high-resoluton screen?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, resolution, external-display, miracast

I just bought a 1440p 21:9 monitor that I had planned on using wirelessly with my laptop from across the living room. I tried using a Miracast dongle (a Microsoft Wireless Display Adapter) but it will only go up to 1080p, and at the wrong aspect ratio.

Do any technologies exist to wirelessly mirror this large of a screen, or at the very least mirror at the correct aspect ratio?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find such a technology at sub-thousands level pricing. I ended up getting a 30ft long DisplayPort. (HDMI works very poorly un-amplified at this cable length!!!)